# npm install - error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler libxmljs@0.18.0 node-gyp rebuild

Tags: node.js, c++11, gcc, node-gyp, libxml-js

I'm running CentOS 6.8(Final) using Vagrant/VirtualBox.
GCC compiler version is (v4.4.7)
Node version (latest LTS): v4.4.6

My package.json file has:

```
{
  "name": "njse",
  "main": "server.js",
  "description": "MyCompany services",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "bunyan": "^1.8.1",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "express-delay": "~0.1.0",
    "libxmljs": "^0.18.0",
    "mssql": "^3.3.0",
    "ping": "^0.1.10",
    "powershell": "^2.0.2",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "q-io": "^1.13.2",
    "validatorjs": "^2.0.11",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.16"
  }
}
```

While running "npm install" or "sudo ~vagrant/bin/npm install" I'm getting the following errors.

Any ideas what should I do to fix this issue and run "npm install" successfully? Thanks.

**Log:**(with some truncation of log files to fit the word limit for this post)

```
[vagrant@localhost my-directory]$ npm install
npm WARN package.json njse@ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json njse@ No README data
npm WARN package.json njse@ No license field.
npm WARN engine dns@0.2.2: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10.0 < 0.11.0"} (current: {"node":"4.4.6","npm":"2.15.5"})
npm WARN engine tomahawk@0.1.6: wanted: {"node":">= 0.8.0 < 0.11.0"} (current: {"node":"4.4.6","npm":"2.15.5"})
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.4.6","npm":"2.15.5"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.4.6","npm":"2.15.5"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.4.6","npm":"2.15.5"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.4.6","npm":"2.15.5"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"4.4.6","npm":"2.15.5"})

> dtrace-provider@0.6.0 install /home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node scripts/install.js


> libxmljs@0.18.0 install /home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/libxmljs
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/libxmljs/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/buf.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/catalog.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xmlschemas.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xmlschemastypes.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xmlstring.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xmlunicode.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xmlwriter.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xpath.o
In file included from ../vendor/libxml/xpath.c:462:
../vendor/libxml/timsort.h: In function ‘libxml_domnode_tim_sort_collapse’:
../vendor/libxml/timsort.h:405: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
../vendor/libxml/xpath.c: At top level:
../vendor/libxml/trionan.c:218: warning: ‘trio_is_negative’ defined but not used
../vendor/libxml/xpath.c: In function ‘xmlXPathCastNumberToString’:
../vendor/libxml/xpath.c:3197: warning: array subscript is above array bounds
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/xpointer.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/vendor/libxml/xml.a
  COPY Release/xml.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/xmljs/src/libxmljs.o
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:43:3: error: #error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.cc:3:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:336: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::MaybeLocal<T>::MaybeLocal()’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:353: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::IsEmpty() const’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:360: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocal(v8::Local<S>*) const’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:364: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘bool v8::WeakCallbackInfo<T>::IsFirstPass() const’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:430: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:469: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::Global<T>::Global()’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:790: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::Global<T>::Global(v8::Global<T>&&)’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:815: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘v8::Global<T>& v8::Global<T>::operator=(v8::Global<S>&&)’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:827: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:852: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:1089: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:1095: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:3205: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<T> v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocalChecked()’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:7164: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:196,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:19: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:24: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:83: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:91: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:98: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:108: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:114: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:118: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:125: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:130: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:135: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:139: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:145: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:150: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:156: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:162: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:168: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:174: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:180: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:186: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:194: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:201: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:205: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:209: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:213: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:217: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:223: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:201,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:14: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MaybeLocal’ with no type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Maybe’ with no type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:26: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:27: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:28: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:29: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:30: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:31: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:32: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:42: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:43: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:44: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:45: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:46: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:59,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:201,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Boolean>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:19: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Number>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:20: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::String>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:21: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Object>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Integer>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:23: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Uint32>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:24: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Int32>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:34: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<bool>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:35: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<double>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:36: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<long int>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<unsigned int>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:38: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::ToFactory<int>’ does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:202,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Integer]’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)’
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Int32]’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)’
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Uint32]’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)’
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:43: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MaybeLocal’ with no type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:43: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:75: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:182: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:183: error: ‘return_t’ does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:189,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:202,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:56: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Date>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Function> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Function>::New(void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:90: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:118: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:197: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::RegExp>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:216: error: ‘return_t’ in 
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:275: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::String>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:281: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::String>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:286: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::String>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:347: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:354: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>’ does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:202,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:293: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::String>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:299: error: ‘return_t’ in 
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:335: error: ‘return_t’ in class ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::RegExp>’ does not name a type
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Error(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::ThrowError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::RangeError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:662: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::ThrowRangeError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:662: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::ReferenceError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:663: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::ThrowReferenceError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:663: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::SyntaxError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:664: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::ThrowSyntaxError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:664: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::TypeError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::ThrowTypeError(const char*)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:673: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:695: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:762: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:768: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘void Nan::Callback::SetFunction(const v8::Local<v8::Function>&)’:
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:3021: error: argument dependent lookup finds ‘class v8::Set’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1404: error:   in call to ‘Set’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function ‘void Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(const char*, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1524: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::AsyncWorker::GetFromPersistent(const char*) const’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1542: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function ‘virtual void Nan::AsyncWorker::HandleErrorCallback()’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1576: error: no matching function for call to ‘New(const char*)’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetMethod(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1896: error: ‘GetFunction’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1897: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetMethod(v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>, const char*, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1908: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetMethod(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, const char*, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1919: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>, const char*, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1933: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Boolean>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::Local<v8::String>, void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<void>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute, Nan::imp::Sig)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1958: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘bool Nan::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<void>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2001: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetNamedPropertyHandler(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Integer>&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Boolean>&), void (*)(const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Array>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2049: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetIndexedPropertyHandler(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, void (*)(uint32_t, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(uint32_t, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Integer>&), void (*)(uint32_t, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Boolean>&), void (*)(const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Array>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2119: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetCallHandler(v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2174: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetCallAsFunctionHandler(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2196: error: ‘NewInstance’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../src/libxmljs.h:7,
                 from ../src/libxmljs.cc:7:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::Export(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE, const char*, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2223: error: no matching function for call to ‘New(const char*&)’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2224: error: ‘GetFunction’ was not declared in this scope
/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/4.4.6/include/node/v8.h:3021: error: argument dependent lookup finds ‘class v8::Set’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2224: error:   in call to ‘Set’
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In constructor ‘Nan::Tap::Tap(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2231: error: no matching function for call to ‘To(v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’
../src/libxmljs.cc:263: error: ‘Set’ is not a member of ‘Nan’
../src/libxmljs.cc:263: error: no matching function for call to ‘New(const char [7])’
make: *** [Release/obj.target/xmljs/src/libxmljs.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/libxmljs/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/vagrant/tools/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/home/vagrant/tools/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/tools/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok

> ws@0.4.31 install /home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/dns/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/dns/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/dns/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'

> ws@0.4.31 install /home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/dns/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/dns/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/node_modules/dns/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/tools/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! libxmljs@0.18.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.18.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs libxmljs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/ws/06272016/my-directory/npm-debug.log
[vagrant@localhost my-directory]$ sudo yum install libxmljs
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: chicago.gaminghost.co
 * epel: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * extras: mirrors.adams.net
 * updates: centos.pymesolutionsweb.com
No package libxmljs available.
Error: Nothing to do
[vagrant@localhost my-directory]$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
[vagrant@localhost my-directory]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
```

Tried upgrading/install of **gcc** using (yum), it says:

```
Package gcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

One of the post says, I may need to install gcc 4.8 or newer to build binary addons for node 4.x and above? Is that really required, if so, how can I efficiently install gcc 4.8 without breaking anything else? I also see there's devtoolset-3-rebuild version available on [CentOS site](http://people.centos.org/tru/). devtoolset-2 has KNOWN issues as per the post: https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

Comment: any update, I got same issue ?

Comment: I'm trying to recall. I think the issue was with the formatting. Instead of {, } (JSON) one of the file during the above operation was reading a file which was having <, > (angle brackets) which is XML format. I did something to solve it but, but wondering if I posted the solution in some other post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on my Linux server:

```
> node-gyp rebuild
...
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:43:3: error: #error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler
```

This helped me:

`$ scl enable devtoolset-2 bash`

Answer (score 0):

We did a mistake and passed `.c extension file` changing extension of those files to `.cpp` fixed this issue for us.